# Determinar el marcador mas cercano. Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Mi proyecto Android trabaja con Google maps, por ende tiene 190 marcadores. El problema al que me enfrento es que me gustaría determinar cual de estos se encuentra mas cercano a mi posición, el problema es que no tengo idea de como hacerlo. Esta es la forma en que agregué los marcadores:

```
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador1).title("Ciclovia Callao").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Alcántara a Sánchez Fontecilla").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador2).title("Ciclovia Antonio Varas").snippet("Calle y Vereda / Bidireccional / Nueva Providencia a Irarrázaval").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador3).title("Ciclovia Cardenal Raúl Silva Henríquez / Américo Vespucio").snippet("Vereda, Calle y Bandejón / Bidireccional / Canal Torrente a Porvenir").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador4).title("Ciclovia Arzobispo Valdivieso").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Comandante Véliz a Ocho Norte").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador5).title("Ciclovia Almirante Blanco Encalada").snippet("Almirante Blanco Encalada").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador6).title("Ciclovia Central Cardenal Silva Henríquez").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Buenaventura a Américo Vespucio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador7).title("Ciclovia Alberto Llona").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Vicente Reyes a 5 de Abril").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador8).title("Ciclovia Clotario Blest").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Carlos Valdovinos a Lo Ovalle").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador9).title("Ciclovia 5 de Abril / Parque por Simón Bolívar").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Vostok a Las Torres").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador10).title("Ciclovia 5 de Abril / Esquina Blanca").snippet("Vereda y bandejón / Bidireccional / Primera Transversal a Concepción del Oro").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador11).title("Ciclovia Carlos Valdovinos").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Santa Rosa a Vicuña Mackenna").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador12).title("Ciclovia Carmen / Las Industrias").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / General Jofré a Comercio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador13).title("Ciclovia Cardenal Raúl Silva Henríquez").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Jorge Quevedo a San Gregorio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador14).title("Ciclovia Chile España").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Simón Bolívar a Miguel de Cervantes").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador15).title("Ciclovia Calle G").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Juan Cristóbal a Juan Muñoz").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador16).title("Ciclovia IV Centenario ").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Los Milagros a Los Pozos").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador17).title("Ciclovia Centenario (a)").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Club Hípico a Bascuñán Guerrero").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador18).title("Ciclovia Alameda / Pajaritos").snippet("Bandejón y Calle / Bidireccional / Teatinos a Escr. Jorge Inostroza").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador19).title("Ciclovia Camino a Melipilla / Pedro Aguirre Cerda").snippet("Calle y vereda / Bidireccional / Avenida Cuatro a Esquina Blanca").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador20).title("Ciclovia Brasil").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Huérfanos a Mapocho").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
```

### Espero que me puedan echar una mano.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;
    String email;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final int PERMS_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        //obtener datos para la barra
        if (user != null) {
            String nombre = user.getDisplayName();
            email = user.getEmail();
            Uri foto = user.getPhotoUrl();

            NavigationView navigationsView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView = navigationsView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView nav_user = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
            TextView name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            ImageView img_user = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            name.setText(nombre);
            nav_user.setText(email);
            Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(img_user);
        } else {
            SharedPreferences loginbdd = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            email = loginbdd.getString("nombre", "");
            String nombre = loginbdd.getString("mail", "");

            NavigationView navigationsView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView = navigationsView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView nav_user = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
            TextView name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            ImageView img_user = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            nav_user.setText(email);
            name.setText(nombre);


            isLocationEnabled();
            if(!isLocationEnabled()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Encienda su GPS")
                        .setMessage("Su GPS se encuentra desactivado, le gustaria activarlo?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Encencer GPS",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPermissions() {
        int res = 0;
        //string array of permissions,
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

        for (String perms : permissions) {
            res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(perms);
            if (!(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPerms() {
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(permissions, PERMS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        boolean allowed = true;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMS_REQUEST_CODE:

                for (int res : grantResults) {
                    // if user granted all permissions.
                    allowed = allowed && (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    onMapReady(map);
                }

                break;
            default:
                // if user not granted permissions.
                allowed = false;
                break;
        }

        if (allowed) {
            onMapReady(map);
        } else {
            // we will give warning to user that they haven't granted permissions.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permisos de Ubicación Denegados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void goLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar).setTitle("Cerrar Aplicación").setMessage("Deseas cerrar CicloMapp?")
                    .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.endSession) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar)
                    .setTitle("Cerrar sessión")
                    .setMessage("Deseas cerrar sesión?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            if (user != null) {
                                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                goLogin();
                            } else {
                                SharedPreferences loginbdd = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginbdd.edit();
                                editor.remove("inicio");
                                editor.commit();
                                goLogin();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.AgregarRuta) {
            //  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, agregarRuta.class);
            // i.putExtra("correo", email);
            // startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.ValorarRuta) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Valoraraciones.class);
            i.putExtra("correo", email);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.ReportarRuta) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reportar.class);
            i.putExtra("correos", email);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.Eventos) {

        } else if (id == R.id.tiendas) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tiendas.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.Leyes) {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

        if (hasPermissions()) {
            map = googleMap;
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-33.447487,-70.673676));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11);
            map.moveCamera(center);
            map.animateCamera(zoom);

            //carga clase polylines y el metodo de agregar las polyline
            Polyline po = new Polyline();
            po.AddPolyline(map);

            //ejecutar snackbar al hacer click en un marcador
            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                    View v1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_main);


                  Snackbar snackbar=  Snackbar.make(v1,"Aqui puedes \n Valorar o Reportar \n la ruta \n seleccionada",12000)
                          .setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
                          .setAction("Opciones", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                            .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar)
                                            .setTitle("Opciones")
                                            .setMessage("Te gustaria valorar o reportar la ruta?")
                                            .setCancelable(true)
                                            .setPositiveButton("Valorar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Valoracion2.class);
                                                    i.putExtra("Nruta", marker.getTitle().toString());
                                                    startActivity(i);
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null)
                                            .setNegativeButton("Reportar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){

                                                }
                                            }).show();
                                }
                            });
                    View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setMaxLines(5);
                    snackbar.show();

                    return false;
                }
            });
            //establecer tamaño del icono y mostrar marcadores
            int height = 50;
            int width = 50;
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mruta);
            Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
            Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
            Marcadores ma=new Marcadores();
            ma.MarcadoreBdd(map,smallMarker);
        }
        else {
            requestPerms();
        }
    }

    protected boolean isLocationEnabled(){
        String le = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(le);
        if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

clase donde tengo los marcadores, colocare 20, para que no sea un post infinito

```
public class Marcadores {
    Connection con;

    public void MarcadoreBdd(GoogleMap map,Bitmap smallMarker) {

        //Marks
        LatLng marcador1 = new LatLng(-33.377763, -70.655048);
        LatLng marcador2 = new LatLng(-33.411492, -70.630575);
        LatLng marcador3 = new LatLng(-33.418552, -70.595004);
        LatLng marcador4 = new LatLng(-33.436021, -70.664835);
        LatLng marcador5 = new LatLng(-33.440952, -70.613127);
        LatLng marcador6 = new LatLng(-33.451081, -70.598126);
        LatLng marcador7 = new LatLng(-33.457891, -70.669612);
        LatLng marcador8 = new LatLng(-33.462861, -70.664945);
        LatLng marcador9 = new LatLng(-33.464718, -70.725187);
        LatLng marcador10 = new LatLng(-33.471569, -70.719421);
        LatLng marcador11 = new LatLng(-33.474207, -70.6351);
        LatLng marcador12 = new LatLng(-33.47576, -70.664878);
        LatLng marcador13 = new LatLng(-33.484084, -70.63058);
        LatLng marcador14 = new LatLng(-33.493925, -70.676427);
        LatLng marcador15 = new LatLng(-33.50299, -70.711023);
        LatLng marcador16 = new LatLng(-33.51035, -70.741265);
        LatLng marcador17 = new LatLng(-33.515225, -70.693527);
        LatLng marcador18 = new LatLng(-33.516518, -70.755622);
        LatLng marcador19 = new LatLng(-33.540047, -70.620863);
        LatLng marcador20 = new LatLng(-33.558337, -70.615721);



        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador1).title("Ciclovia Callao").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Alcántara a Sánchez Fontecilla").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador2).title("Ciclovia Antonio Varas").snippet("Calle y Vereda / Bidireccional / Nueva Providencia a Irarrázaval").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador3).title("Ciclovia Cardenal Raúl Silva Henríquez / Américo Vespucio").snippet("Vereda, Calle y Bandejón / Bidireccional / Canal Torrente a Porvenir").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador4).title("Ciclovia Arzobispo Valdivieso").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Comandante Véliz a Ocho Norte").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador5).title("Ciclovia Almirante Blanco Encalada").snippet("Almirante Blanco Encalada").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador6).title("Ciclovia Central Cardenal Silva Henríquez").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Buenaventura a Américo Vespucio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador7).title("Ciclovia Alberto Llona").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Vicente Reyes a 5 de Abril").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador8).title("Ciclovia Clotario Blest").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Carlos Valdovinos a Lo Ovalle").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador9).title("Ciclovia 5 de Abril / Parque por Simón Bolívar").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Vostok a Las Torres").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador10).title("Ciclovia 5 de Abril / Esquina Blanca").snippet("Vereda y bandejón / Bidireccional / Primera Transversal a Concepción del Oro").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador11).title("Ciclovia Carlos Valdovinos").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Santa Rosa a Vicuña Mackenna").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador12).title("Ciclovia Carmen / Las Industrias").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / General Jofré a Comercio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador13).title("Ciclovia Cardenal Raúl Silva Henríquez").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Jorge Quevedo a San Gregorio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador14).title("Ciclovia Chile España").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Simón Bolívar a Miguel de Cervantes").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador15).title("Ciclovia Calle G").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Juan Cristóbal a Juan Muñoz").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador16).title("Ciclovia IV Centenario ").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Los Milagros a Los Pozos").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador17).title("Ciclovia Centenario (a)").snippet("Bandejón / Bidireccional / Club Hípico a Bascuñán Guerrero").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador18).title("Ciclovia Alameda / Pajaritos").snippet("Bandejón y Calle / Bidireccional / Teatinos a Escr. Jorge Inostroza").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador19).title("Ciclovia Camino a Melipilla / Pedro Aguirre Cerda").snippet("Calle y vereda / Bidireccional / Avenida Cuatro a Esquina Blanca").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador20).title("Ciclovia Brasil").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Huérfanos a Mapocho").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo mejor seria calcular las distancias entre tu posición y las de tus marcadores

```
public static double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
           Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
           Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = (double) (earthRadius * c);

    return dist;
}
```

Esta funcion, extraida de [pregunta stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java) calcula la distancia entre dos direcciones en **metros**

Como tienes las latitudes y longitudes de todos tus marcadores, cuando los armes, envia a esta funcion tu latitud y tu longitud para obtener la distancia en metros. Algo asi :

```
public void masCercano(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2){
  double distance = distFrom(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2);
   if(this.contador == 0){
      this.distancia = distance;
      this.latitud_cercana = lat1;
      this.longitud_cercana = lng1;
      this.contador++;
   }else{
       if(distance <= this.distancia){
           this.distancia = distance;
           this.latitud_cercana = lat1;
           this.longitud_cercana = lng1;
       }
   }
}
```

Y asi obtienes la menor de las distancias siendo 0 si es que estas ahi mismo.

```
marcador1 = new LatLng(-33.377763, -70.655048);
this.masCercano(-33.377763, -70.655048, ti_latitud, tu_longitud);
```

Donde `latitud_cercana` y `longitud_cercana` seria tus datos para el marcador mas cercano.

Esto quedaria asi :

```
public class Test {
    public double distancia = 0.0;
    public double latitud_cercana = 0;
    public double longitud_cercana = 0;
    public static double mi_latitud = -33.3916818;
    public static double mi_longitud = -70.6157192;
    public int contador = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ArrayList < Marcador > marcadores = new ArrayList < Marcador > ();
        marcadores.add(new Marcador(-33.3908577, -70.6170388));
        marcadores.add(new Marcador(-33.3956634, -70.6159224));
        //marcadores.add(new Marcador(-33.3916818, -70.6157192));
        marcadores.add(new Marcador(-33.3838813, -70.6247515));
        Test a = new Test();
        for (Marcador object: marcadores) {
            a.masCercano(object.latitud, object.longitud, mi_latitud, mi_longitud);
        }
        System.out.println("Distancia = " + a.distancia);
        System.out.println("Latitud cercana  = " + a.latitud_cercana);
        System.out.println("Longitud cercana = " + a.longitud_cercana);
    }

    public static double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
        double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLng / 2) * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double dist = (double)(earthRadius * c);

        return dist;
    }

    public void masCercano(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
        double distance = distFrom(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2);
        if (this.contador == 0) {
            this.distancia = distance;
            this.latitud_cercana = lat1;
            this.longitud_cercana = lng1;
            this.contador++;
        } else {
            if (distance <= this.distancia) {
                this.distancia = distance;
                this.latitud_cercana = lat1;
                this.longitud_cercana = lng1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: con este metodo, deberia ingresar los marcadores uno por uno?

Comment: Claro, o tienes la opcion de crear un arreglo con todos tus marcadores y en un foreach recorrer tus latitudes y longitudes y llamar a este metodo.

Comment: y que variable, es la que me devolvería la distancia?

Comment: Ninguna, se define al principio de tu clase la variable y se va modificando a medida que vas llamando a tu metodo, la variable distancia es la que siempre obtiene la menor pero la variable latitud_cercana y longitud_cercana es la que determina la latitud y longitud mas cercana a ti

Comment: pero si agrego un foreach, esta no se ira sobrescribiendo y por ende la mas cercana no se podrá determinar?

Comment: Se determina porque al iniciar == 0 marca una de referencia y despues va comparando con la que va entrando al foreach, si entra modifica el valor, si no pasa de largo hay dos opciones 1 que sea igual a 0 (que estas ahi mismo) o dos que sea menor a una anterior

Comment: entiendo, pero en el caso que todas sean mayor a 0, estas se irán sobrescribiendo a mi parecer y no se almacenaria en la variable  la que contenga la menor distancia

Comment: Si se almacenan, ya que si es mayor a 0 se guarda en las variables y se guarda tambien distancia, al pasar a la siguiente se compara LA ANTERIOR guardada con la nueva SI la nueva es menor a la ANTIGUA la sobreescribe, si no, pasa.

Comment: voy a probar con tu respuesta, si me funciona, los 50 son tuyos

Comment: no logro, hacer que me devuelva un valor :(

Comment: Q te devuelve?? Debes evaluar las variables no un retorno

Comment: estoy evaluando la variable distancia, el problema es que me la retorna nula, siendo que los puntos son distintos

Comment: Como la estas declarando? Segun mi codigo jamas es nula es 0. Imprime el valor de distance

Comment: @zhet actualice mi respuesta, corregí algunos errores y funciona a la perfeccion

Comment: me funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: @zhet me alegro se haberte ayudado aqui y en las demas preguntas, un abrazo amigo

Comment: gracias a ti, te diste el tiempo de ayudarme en todas las preguntas que tuve :)

Answer (score 5):

Puedes determinar la distancia usando a la clase [`Location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html).

Por ejemplo, recorre todas las distancias de tus marcadores y guárdalas en un mapa.

```
private static float distance(LatLng marcador, Location miUbicacion){
    Location cL = new Location("");
    cL.setLatitude(marcador.latitude);
    cL.setLongitude(marcador.longitude);

    return miUbicacion.distanceTo(cL);
}
```

Después utiliza el método `Collections.min()` para saber cual es la distancia mas cercana a tu posición actual. Con la sentencia siguiente sacarías esa información al Log del dispositivo:

```
Log.i("TAG", "Valor mínimo: " + Collections.min(mapDistance.keySet()));
```

**EDITADO**

Tomando en cuenta la información anterior, genere un método que me devuelve un listado de LatLong.

Debes recorrer el listado y crear un mapa para guardar la distancia (Key) obtenida del método distance() y asociar la LatLong(Value) del cual se obtiene, posteriormente debes pasar el mapDistance al método Collections.min() para saber cual es la distancia mínima del mapa.
Con la ayuda de la distancia minima que te devuelve obtienes la LatLong del mapa.

```
  private void encuentraMasCercano(){
    //Variable para verificar el tiempo que se tarda en ejecutar todo el método
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    //LatLng de mi ubicación
    LatLng miLatLng = new LatLng(-33.461496, -70.659317);
    //Location de mi ubicación
    Location miLocation = new Location("");
    miLocation.setLatitude(miLatLng.latitude);
    miLocation.setLongitude(miLatLng.longitude);
    //Listado de LatLong de ejemplo
    List<LatLng> latLngList = getList();
    //Mapa con un tamaño definido para el ejemplo
    Map<Float, LatLng> mapDistance = new HashMap<>(20);

    for (LatLng latLng : latLngList){
        float distance = distance(latLng, miLocation);
        Log.d("TAG" , "Distance : "+ distance);
        mapDistance.put(distance, latLng);
    }

    float min = Collections.min(mapDistance.keySet());
    //Obtienes la LatLng mas cercano a tu ubicación
    LatLng latLngMasCercano = mapDistance.get(min);

    Log.d("TAG" , "Distancia : "+ min  + " Latitude " + latLngMasCercano.latitude  + " Longitude : " +latLngMasCercano.longitude);

    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    Log.d("TAG", " time : " + time );
 }
```

Saludos.

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo, donde pueda guiarme?

Comment: Un ejemplo completo no amigo, solo debes hacer un for, guardar las distancias y pasarla por Collections.min(list)

Comment: Es una solución, sí, pero esto sería improductivo para un volumen de puntos grande.

Comment: 190 no me parece un volumen grande, pero trataré de mejorar mi respuesta

Comment: @Keops, sabes de otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: No amigo, has intentado hacerlo de la manera que te indique? Tarda mucho en realizarlo?

Comment: @Keops, la verdad, no entendi, creo que me estoy complicado mucho con tu solucion

Comment: Añade el código de tu activity o fragment para poder ayudarte

Comment: @Keops, agregue el codigo

Comment: A mi me parece una buena solucion, considerando que el volumen no es grande para una coleccion, en tiempo no demoraria nada en recorrerlas +1

Comment: No, no, por supuesto que 190 puntos es un volumen de puntos en el que hacer una búsqueda lineal no va a suponer una demora de tiempo muy grande respecto a búsquedas indexadas. Pero si por ejemplo, el tamaño de puntos va creciendo en el tiempo, quizás si sea conveniente tener ordenados los puntos en un Quadtree (por ejemplo), para agilizar búsquedas.

Answer (score 2):

Ademas de las respuestas dadas, debes tener en cuenta que Google ya provee la libreria [`Google Maps Android API utility library`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) que no solo implementa un método para calcular la distancia entre dos puntos GPS ([`computeDistanceBetween`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeDistanceBetween-LatLng-LatLng-) para dos objetos `LatLng`), sino que también incluye otros métodos muy convenientes como calcular el *Heading* (o la dirección que hay que tomar desde un punto al otro) y otros métodos útiles para áreas y calculo de longitud de un Path, ademas de otras utilidades.

Luego, al igual que las otras soluciones, como en Maps **no tienes un método para listar los marcadores cargados en el mapa**, lo tienes que resolver por tu cuenta, cargando en un arreglo o `List<LatLng>` todos los marcadores que te interesan y luego iterar sobre dicha lista comparando esas posiciones con tu posición actual para averiguar cual es el mas cercano.

Ejemplo:

Cuando agregas los markers.. también deberás agregarlos en una lista o arreglo

```
   List<LatLng> marcadores = new ArrayList<>();

   marcadores.add(marcador1);
   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador1).title("Ciclovia Callao").snippet("Calle / Bidireccional / Alcántara a Sánchez Fontecilla").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

   marcadores.add(marcador2);
   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marcador2).title("Ciclovia Antonio Varas").snippet("Calle y Vereda / Bidireccional / Nueva Providencia a Irarrázaval").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

   // etc
```

Luego, Suponiendo que `miPos` tiene el la posición en que te encuentras:

```
LatLon miPos = new LatLon(<aquí va tu posición>);
LatLng posicionMasCercana = null;
double distanciaActual = Double.MAX_VALUE;

for(int i=0; i < marcadores.size(); i++) {
    double distancia = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(miPos, marcadores.get(i));
    if (distanciaActual > distancia) {
        posicionMasCercana = marcadores.get(i);
        distanciaActual = distancia;
    }
}

// en este punto, posicionMasCercana, tiene la latitud y longitud del punto
// mas cercano a miPos
```